# Matching A File Name Using Grep

Tags: regex, bash

The overarching problem:
So I have a file name that comes in the form of 
JohnSmith14_120325_A10_6.raw
and I want to match it using regex. I have a couple of issues in building a working example but unfortunately my issues won't be solved unless I get the basics.

So I have just recently learned about piping and one of the cool things I learned was that I can do the following.

```
X=ll_paprika.sc (don't ask)
VAR=`echo $X | cut -p -f 1`
echo $VAR
```

which gives me paprika.sc
Now when I try to execute the pipe idea in grep, nothing happens.

```
x=ll_paprika.sc
VAR=`echo $X | grep *.sc`
echo $VAR
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Second question:
How does one match a single underscore using regex?

Here's what I am ultimately trying to do;

```
VAR=`echo $X | grep -e "^[a-bA-Z][a-bA-Z0-9]*(_){1}[0-9]*(_){1}[a-bA-Z0-9]*(_){1}[0-9](\.){1}(raw)"
```

So the basic idea of my pattern here is that the file name must start with a letter 
and then it can have any number of letters and numbers following it and it must have an _ delimit a series of numbers and another _ to delimit the next set of numbers and characters and another _ to delimit the next set of numbers and then it must have a single period following by raw. This looks grossly wrong and ugly (because I am not sure about the syntax). So how does one match a file extension? Can someone put up a simple example for something ll_parpika.sc so that I can figure out how to do my own regex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
x=ll_paprika.sc
VAR=`echo $X | grep *.sc`
echo $VAR
```

The reason this isn't doing what you want is that the grep matches a line and returns it. `*.sc` does in fact match `11_paprika.sc`, so it returns that whole line and sticks it in `$VAR`.

If you want to just get a part of it, the `cut` line probably better. There is a `grep -o` option that returns only the matching portion, but for this you'd basically have to put in the thing you were looking for, at which point why bother?

> the file name must start with a letter

`grep -e "^[a-zA-Z]

> and then it can have any number
>   of letters and numbers following it

[a-zA-Z0-9]*

> and it must have an _ delimit a
>   series of numbers and another _ to delimit the next set of numbers and
>   characters and another _ to delimit the next set of numbers

(_[0-9]+){3}

> and then it must have a single period following by raw.

.raw"

Answer (score 0):

For the first, use:

```
VAR=`echo $X | egrep '\.sc$'`
```

For the second, you can try this alternative instead:

```
VAR=`echo $X | egrep '^[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*_[[:digit:]]+_[[:alnum:]]+_[[:digit:]]+\.raw'`
```

Note that your character classes from your expression differ from the description that follows in that they seem to only be permissive of a-b for lower case characters in some places. This example is permissive of all alphanumeric characters in those places.